# unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

Trying to install from a USB live image and getting the following - 
[  26.952015] ata3: COMRESET failed (erro=16)
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21-0-1unbuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system.

background.  root, swap and home partitions are already set up.
Using the Freya i386 ISO (latest) passed checksum.
Used rufus to put extract the ISO image onto the USB thumbdrive.
I reboot using this thumb drive.  The first thing that comes up is a 
COMRESET message, shortly thereafter the elementary logo comes up and stays
on screen for a good 5 to 8 seconds.  Then I get the error message above.

Anyone know why?  My DVD is shot, and I'll happily go get one to try and install from it tomorrow; but if there is a way to fix this then I'd just as soon get the install finished.

Finally had it with Windows.  Windows 10 is not going on my systems.

Thanks in advance for any assist.

randyv

Comment: (erro=16) should have been (errno=16)